# Composer : How to ignore the installing/updating of some dependancies?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm on one project where this is it dependancies list

```
{
    "name": "my/package",
    "description": "My new project",
    "require": [
       "another/package": "1.0.0",
       //...
    ],
    "require-dev" => [
         "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
         //....
    ]
}
```

And on `another/package`, this is the `composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "another/package",
    "description": "My new other project",
    "require-dev" => [
         "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
         //....
    ]
}
```

`another/package` use too `phpunit/phpunit` in the version < to what is used in `my/project`. There is a possibility to ignore the installing of phpunit/phpunit in `another/package` ?

Comment: Just remove "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0", from the composer.json if you don't want to use it as a dependency and it will not be installed (also don't forget to composer update)

Comment: Problem is that it's not my package !

Comment: If you don't do unit testing on the project you can remove it and it will not affect your project functionality

Comment: Your example looks incorrect. Composer is not installing dependencies from  `require-dev` of dependencies. So if you're installing `my/package`, `require-dev` section from `another/package` will be completely ignored and there will be no conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it.

[Dependency Hell in Composer #2609](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2609)

However you can [try this technique](https://doghouse.agency/article/resolving-php-composer-dependency-conflicts).

Other options:

1. See if using phpunit 5.0 in my/project is not an issue
2. See if there is a version of another/package that requires phpunit 6.0